# Disable index rotation in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

By default, logstash create indices in the format logstash-YYYY.MM.DD, which essentially creates one index per day. Is it possible to disable this feature and force logstash to push data to a specific index name?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) in your logstash configuration. If that's the case, you can add the [`index` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index) to your output configuration, i.e. without pattern, just a normal index name (without uppercase characters, though)

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        index => "your_index_name"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the best Val ! :) Thanks again for your help.